# restructuring pandas dataframe, creating new columns from multi levels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following example dataset, and I'm trying to restructure it so that I have more `values` columns for each level of `SUBJECT`, `block_name`, and `condition_name`, preferably prepended to the new column names. I've tried unstacking and pivoting, but have no success just errors.

```
SUBJECT block_name  condition_name  values
5   A   S   0.96
5   A   C   1.00
5   F   S   0.92
5   F   C   0.93
5   Te  S   0.85
5   Te  C   0.71
5   To  S   0.88
5   To  C   1.00
6   A   S   0.96
6   A   C   1.00
6   F   S   0.92
6   F   C   0.71
6   Te  S   1.00
6   Te  C   1.00
6   To  S   0.69
6   To  C   0.86
7   A   S   1.00
7   A   C   1.00
7   F   S   0.88
7   F   C   0.93
7   Te  S   0.85
7   Te  C   1.00
7   To  S   0.62
7   To  C   0.93
```

So for example, I'd like to be left with the following:

```
SUBJECT A_S_values  A_C_values  F_S_values  F_C_values  Te_S_values Te_C_values To_S_values To_C_values
5   0.96    1.00    0.92    0.93    0.85    0.71    0.88    1.00
6   0.96    1.00    0.92    0.71    1.00    1.00    0.69    0.86
7   1.00    1.00    0.88    0.93    0.85    1.00    0.62    0.93
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) by 2 levels of `MultiIndex` and then flatten columns names in `list comprehension`:

```
df = df.set_index(['SUBJECT','block_name','condition_name'])['values'].unstack([1,2])
#python 3.6+ solution
df.columns = [f'{i}_{j}_values' for i, j in df.columns]
#python bellow 3.6
#df.columns = ['{}_{}_values'.format(i, j) for i, j in df.columns]
print (df)
         A_S_values  A_C_values  F_S_values  F_C_values  Te_S_values  \
SUBJECT                                                                
5              0.96         1.0        0.92        0.93         0.85   
6              0.96         1.0        0.92        0.71         1.00   
7              1.00         1.0        0.88        0.93         0.85   

         Te_C_values  To_S_values  To_C_values  
SUBJECT                                         
5               0.71         0.88         1.00  
6               1.00         0.69         0.86  
7               1.00         0.62         0.93
```

Last if necessary:

```
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   SUBJECT  A_S_values  A_C_values  F_S_values  F_C_values  Te_S_values  \
0        5        0.96         1.0        0.92        0.93         0.85   
1        6        0.96         1.0        0.92        0.71         1.00   
2        7        1.00         1.0        0.88        0.93         0.85   

   Te_C_values  To_S_values  To_C_values  
0         0.71         0.88         1.00  
1         1.00         0.69         0.86  
2         1.00         0.62         0.93
```

Comment: this is great! if I were to have a second column, say 'values_2', how would we go about fitting that in here as well? would we just have to make it separately and then merge the two dataframes or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: @fffrost Yes, you are right. or use concat with removing. reset_index() from this solution.